# Failed to resolve 'version' as a valid ref. when run git tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, git

I run this code

```
git tag -a v1.0 -m initial version
```

And then I get this error

```
Fatal: Failed to resolve 'version' as a valid ref.
```

I just changed the version of my python package to upload to pypi. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh, I found the error. I forgot to use double quotes on the messages.

```
git tag -a v1.0 -m "initial version"
```